# Set and reference variables in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline across Stages

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to determine Github Organization by setting a variable(GIT_ORG) using withEnv and reference later in Checkout Stage, but not able to do that, I am using Jenkins Scripted Pipeline for this with 'node' and multiple 'stage'(s). Current job is failing while cloning Git repository as there is no valid ${GIT_ORG} in checkout.
I also wanted to use withEnv variable across Stages, not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
  stage( 'Checkout - TIBCO BW') {
    sh '/app/aims/scripts/folder.sh'
      sh 'echo "Checkout TIBCO BW CODE"'
   if (env.MDM_BW == 'true') {
         withEnv(["GIT_ORG=Enterprise-MDM"]){
         echo env.GIT_ORG
        }
    } else {
        withEnv(["GIT_ORG=Enterprise-Integrations"]){
        echo $GIT_ORG
        }
    }                    
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: '$GIT_CODE_TAG']], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
        extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
        relativeTargetDir: '${TIBCO_EARNAME}/code']], 
        submoduleCfg: [], 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'GIT_USER', url: 'git@github.company.com:${GIT_ORG}/${TIBCO_EARNAME}.git']]])
        //workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try below script:

```
if (env.MDM_BW == 'true') {
        environment{
            GIT_ORG=Enterprise-MDM
           }
    } else {
        environment{
            GIT_ORG=Enterprise-Integrations
           }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Amit. I have tried it, still not working. Checkout in the same Stage has code to clone from Git, which is where I wanted to refer **GIT_ORG** variable. Can you suggest how to refer that variable which is initialized inside **IF** loop. Thanks for the help again!!

Comment: If it doesn't have to be assigned to the environment, you could define a global variable outside the stages, then set it inside your if statement.

Comment: Ya, I don't want an environment variable, but how would I refer the global variable in subsequent stages in a scripted pipeline. Sorry I am really not a Devops guy, just trying to help one of them.